# Raiden: only for ERC20 transfers?

Tags: erc-20, raiden

Is [Raiden network](https://raiden.network/) only suited for ERC20 token transfers? Does / will it support other token standards (e.g., ERC223) or simple ETH payments?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently only ERC20 tokens. For one thing, it uses the `approve()`/`transferFrom()` mechanism that ERC20 provides, but ERC223 doesn't.

However, other non-ERC20 tokens and Ether itself can fairly simply be wrapped into ERC20-compliant tokens using smart contracts (E.g. you send the contract some Ether; you get back some ERC20 tokens that you can convert back to Ether at any time via the same contract at a 1:1 rate). So this limitation is not as severe as it may seem initially. This process could even be automated by the Raiden client or netting contract.

Comment: is there any super simple ERC20 token contract that mimics ETH 1 to 1 already in main net? I've heard about WETH and PETH but...